# exercise: calculate the variance using arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a problem and I don't know why it happens.
This is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int VALNUM = 14; //initializes 14 variables for grades

double grades[VALNUM]; // initializes grades array
double deviation[VALNUM]; // initializes deviation array to store the calculated values

int i; // for loops

double total, average, total2, variance; // for calculations

cout << "enter 14 grades: ";

for(i = 0; i < VALNUM; i++) // this loop enters the grades then adds it too total
{
    cin >> grades[i];
    total = total + grades[i];
    cout << endl;
}

average = total / VALNUM; // this divides the total number of grades and the number being entered

for(i = 0; i < VALNUM; i++) // this loop calculates grades per subscript - average and assigned in deviation
{
    deviation[i] = grades[i] - average;
}

cout << "\nthe numbers you entered is deviated to: ";

for(i = 0; i < VALNUM; i++) // this outputs the first results
{
    cout << "\ngrade [" << i << "] = " << deviation[i] << endl;
}

cout << "calculating the variance: " << endl;

for(i = 0; i < VALNUM; i++) // this calculates using variance
{
    total2 = (deviation[i] * deviation[i]) + total2;
}

VALNUM = VALNUM - 1;
variance = total2 / VALNUM;

cout << "the variance of the grades is: " << variance // outputs the results
     << endl;

return 0;
}
```

at first the output was this

```
enter 14 grades: 89 95 72 83 99 54 86  75 92  73  79 75 82 73

the numbers youve entered is deviated into

grades[0] = 8.5
      .
      .
      .
grades[13] = -7.5


calculating the variance:

the variance of the grades is: 134.12
```

The first it was fine but when I launch the second time

```
   enter the 14 grades: xx xx xx xx .....

   the numbers youve entered is deviated into:

   grade[0] = 1.0831e+096
             .
             .  
             .
```

and all the results are the same just like in `grade[0]`

Is there some solution to this ? 
It will be surely helpful.

Comment: Initialize all your variables! (BTW, your arrays are not standard C++, you're using VLAs which is C99.)

Comment: what do you mean initialize can u explain whats wrong and how can i fix this?

Comment: When you write `double foo;` (or any other primitive type) inside a function, that variable is not initialized - it contains a garbage value. You need to set them whatever it is they need to be set to for your algorithm to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, define a len for your arrays, then initilize your variables with 0's.

```
#define len 14
int VALNUM = len;
double grades[len] = {0};
double deviation[len] = {0};
double total = 0;
double total2 = 0;
```

EDIT: thanks to Robert for edit

Comment: Shouldn't they be initialized with `double`s, i.e. `0.0`?

Comment: @JonnyHenly I didn't see any difference in the final effect.

Comment: He should initialize the other variables too, especially `total`

Comment: i try your code but error comes  variable sized objects grades may not be initialized and variable sized objects deviation may not be initialized

Comment: @KrysselTillada you can not use a non-const variable to specify the length of an array. but you can     #define it.

Comment: @KrysselTillada: The main thing that `#define len` does is break any code that tries to use `len` as an identifer, so don't do that. In general, don't use the preprocessor with a very good reason. Just make your variable `const`.

Comment: yeah it works but if i chage const int VALNUM = xx i cant change the variable inside it any solution? i use valnum in for subtracting in order to divide it to total2 to calculate the variance

Comment: @KrysselTillada const int startValnum = xx; int VALNUM = startValnum; and grades[startValnum];